# How to know the shape of sparse tensor in tensorflow 2.8

Tags: printing, tensorflow2.0, shapes

I am trying to understand the code given [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/main/ml/recommendation-systems/recommendation-systems.ipynb?utm_source=ss-recommendation-systems&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=recommendation-systems) by Google. It has a line as below in the function `def build_model(ratings, embedding_dim=3, init_stddev=1.)`

```
U = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(
      [A_train.dense_shape[0], embedding_dim], stddev=init_stddev))
```

Its assigning random values to user vector `U`. What is not clear is how is `A_train.dense_shape[0]` getting its value from. All the online documentation states that without using an session.run we cant get value from an tensor, since I am using tensorflow 2.8 so hoepfully without using session.run we will get values. Now the problem is when I try to print the same inside or out side the function I am not getting satisfactory result even with tensorflow2.X

Below are all the print that I have tried

1. `tf.print(A_train.dense_shape[0])`
2. `print(A_train.dense_shape[0])`

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong here. My tensorflow version is 2.8.2

Answer (score 0):

When we write `tf.print(A_train.dense_shape[0])` then the calculation is still in graph, this graph must then be executed, we can do that using below code

```
trr, ter = split_dataframe(ratings) ## this function is defined in the colab notebook given by Google
A_trr = build_rating_sparse_tensor(trr)  ## this function is defined in the colab notebook given by Google
A_trr_shape=tf.print(A_trr.dense_shape[1]) ## print the output 
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(A_trr_shape) ## execute the shape graph
```